# How can I obtain relayed_by IP via Blockchain Data API?

Tags: blockchain, blockchain.info

I have tried to look for "relayed_by" IP address via the Blockchain Data API for a few transactions but it always returns "relayed_by":"0.0.0.0". For example,

https://blockchain.info/rawtx/b6f6991d03df0e2e04dafffcd6bc418aac66049e2cd74b80f14ac86db1e3f0da

Not sure whether I have made anything mistakenly. Any advice on alternative API for relayed by IP address please?

Thanks a lot.